# How to add settings.xml to build process of Jenkins to docker image

Tags: xml, maven, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have `Jenkinsfile` in my repository:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'slavedev'}

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                   image 'myimage:latest'
                   }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -version'

            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Dockerfile` of `myimage`:

```
ROM maven:latest

COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/
```

When i am trying to start manually this image via `docker run -it  myimage:latest /bin/bash`, i see:

```
root@9a963055c12f:/tmp# ls -lta /root/.m2/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  129 Jul 21 18:53 copy_reference_file.log
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   82 Jul 21 18:53 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  327 Jul 21 18:53 settings-docker.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    6 Jul 21 18:53 repository
drwx------ 1 root root   17 Jul 21 17:58 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2897 Jul 21 17:57 settings.xml
```

How you see, we have `settings.xml` in `.m2`.
But, when i am trying to execute `Jenkins-job` with downloading of sources, i see, that:

```
     [exec] [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
     [exec] [DEBUG] Reading user settings from ?/.m2/settings.xml
```

And also, i don't see, what in Docker-container. I see only list of my sources.

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 jenkins jenkins    41 Jul 21 17:52 src
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  3212 Jul 21 17:52 build.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 32014 Jul 21 17:52 pom.xml
```

And job, that works locally, does not work in the container. Really, i tried everything, please help! I played with everything, I don't sleep two nights, but i am really can't find, how to run this!
`setting.xml` file with private repository and credentials to this repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `settings.xml` by option `-s`

```
sh 'mvn -s /root/.m2/settings.xml -version'
```

You check jenkins run the container with which user from the build log. If it's not run with `root` user, Maven won't use the settings.xml from `/root/.m2`.